# Permission denied while executing hadoop example in standalone mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run hadoop on standalone mode. when I try to execute the command

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-mapred-examples-0.21.0.jar grep input output
```

I am getting following errors:

```
laxmikant@laxmikant-Inspiron-1464:~/Work/hadoop-0.21.0$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-mapred-  examples-0.21.0.jar grep input output
/home/laxmikant/Work/hadoop-0.21.0/bin/hadoop-config.sh: line 189:     /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: Permission denied
bin/hadoop: line 120: /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: Permission denied
bin/hadoop: line 120: exec: /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: cannot execute:     Permission denied
```

How to remove errors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user from which you are running `hadoop` doesn't have privilege to run `java`. 
but by looking at the path where java's binary is located(/home/laxmikant/java/) it should be easily accessible to either the user `laxmikant` or to the root user. So if you are trying to execute it as user `laxmikant` and still getting the error, then, perhaps there is no Java installed properly. Also make sure you set `JAVA_HOME` correctly in hadoop's conf/hadoop-env.sh .

Comment: I have installed java path correctly... which java gives correct path.

Comment: Now it is saying -  bash: /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: Permission denied
bash: /home/laxmikant/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: Permission denied